# Spell check only works in one tab in MacVim

Tags: macvim

If I open a single file with MacVim, and I use `:set spell`, spell check works fine. However, if I open more tabs within that instance of MacVim, and I use `:set spell`, spell check does not work for those tabs. Although, it still works for the first tab I opened. How can I get spell check to work for the other tabs I opened?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  After

```
$ mvim /tmp/foo.txt
:set spell
:tab sp /tmp/bar.txt
:set spell?
```

I see that `'spell'` is set in the second buffer; "foo" and "quux" are highlighted as not real words, but "bar" is good.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experimentation, it depends **when** you `:set spell`.
If I `:set spell` and then open new tabs, the setting carries over.  However, if I create several new tabs and only *then* `:set spell` on a single tab, it applies to that tab alone].

This [wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Run_a_command_in_multiple_buffers) has instructions on how to run a command in multiple tabs.  It looks like you want `:tabdo set spell`.